# How to instantiate class in another class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, instance

How to instantiate class in another class in javascript?
A class has static and non static method

```
export default class MyClass {
    static staticMethod() {
        return console.log(`this is static method`);
    }

    nonStaticMethod() {
        return console.log(`this is not static method`);
    }

}
```

I can access static method from above in some other js file which is class like this:

```
import MyClass form "somewhere";
MyClass.staticMethod(); //this works
```

But how can I access non static method?

```
//This does not work
import MyClass form "somewhere";
MyClass.nonStaticMethod();
```

In order for this to work, instance of MyClass needs to be created/passed. How can I do something like this?

```
let myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.nonStaticMethod();
//I am getting uncaught ReferenceError: nonStaticMethod is not defined
```

Comment: don't use a non-static method

Comment: That is the entire point of a static method. It doesn't require you to instantiate a whole new class.

Comment: Don't name your instance variable the same as your class. `let myClass = new myClass()` will error.

Comment: @mwilson OP is saying theyre getting an error trying to call the non static method on an instance of `myClass`.

Comment: @SteamDev, that was a type. I fixed it.

Comment: @SteamDev: Negative. I don't see any instantiation of a `new` class here: `import myClass form "somewhere";
myClass.nonStaticMethod();`

Comment: @user7331530 Is the imported name `myClass` or `MyClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of the class, then call the instance method. You cant call an instance method from a static context like that. See the sample code below:

```js
class ClassA {
  static staticMethod() {
    return 'this is static method';
  }

  nonStaticMethod() {
    return 'this is not static method';
  }
}

//Call static method:
console.log(ClassA.staticMethod()); //Works as expected
//ClassA.nonStaticMethod(); // Uncomment and see it Will cause a Uncaught TypeError

//Call instance method:
const instance = new ClassA();
//console.log(instance.staticMethod());  // Uncomment and see it Will cause a Uncaught TypeError
console.log(instance.nonStaticMethod()); //Works as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see anything wrong here. This code works just fine.

```js
class myClass {
    static staticMethod() {
        return console.log(`this is static method`);
    }

    nonStaticMethod() {
        return console.log(`this is not static method`);
    }
}

myClass.staticMethod();
let classInstance = new myClass();
classInstance.nonStaticMethod();
```